# System Notification with JavaScript (Chrome for Android)

Tags: javascript, notifications

I've developed a very small and simple chat app with Go and JavaScript. Now I want to make a system notification, if someone sends a message. This works like a charm for all desktop browsers, but on Android I don't get this to work.
I've done a search to see if Chrome implements the Notification API and I have found different results. Does somebody know if it does? If not, what can I do instead of that? I've thought about an alert, but this is not a nice solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i took information from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/notification), seems like not supported

[image]